# Parquet file sink to azure blob

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have implemented the following sink:

```
object ParquetSink {

  def parquetFileSink[A <: Message: ClassTag](
      assigner: A => String,
      config: Config
  )(implicit lc: LoggingConfigs): FileSink[A] = {
    val bucketAssigner = new BucketAssigner[A, String] {
      override def getBucketId(element: A, context: BucketAssigner.Context): String = {
        val path = assigner(element)
        logger.info(LogMessage(-1, s"Writing file to ${config.getString(baseDirKey)}/$path", "NA"))
        path
      }

      override def getSerializer: SimpleVersionedSerializer[String] = SimpleVersionedStringSerializer.INSTANCE
    }

    def builder(outFile: OutputFile): ParquetWriter[A] =
      new ParquetProtoWriters.ParquetProtoWriterBuilder(
        outFile,
        implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]
      ).withCompressionCodec(config.getCompression(compressionKey)).build()

    val parquetBuilder: ParquetBuilder[A] = path => builder(path)
    FileSink
      .forBulkFormat(
        new Path(s"wasbs://${config.getString(baseDirKey)}@${config.getString(accountNameKey)}.blob.core.windows.net"),
        new ParquetWriterFactory[A](parquetBuilder)
      )
      .withBucketAssigner(bucketAssigner)
      .withOutputFileConfig(
        OutputFileConfig
          .builder()
          .withPartSuffix(".parquet")
          .build()
      )
      .build()
  }
}
```

After deploying it I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Recoverable writers on AzureBlob are only supported for ABFS 
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azurefs.AzureBlobRecoverableWriter.checkSupportedFSSchemes(AzureBlobRecoverableWriter.java:44) ~[?:?]                                                          
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azure.common.hadoop.HadoopRecoverableWriter.<init>(HadoopRecoverableWriter.java:57) ~[?:?]                                                                    
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azurefs.AzureBlobRecoverableWriter.<init>(AzureBlobRecoverableWriter.java:37) ~[?:?]                                                                          
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azurefs.AzureBlobFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:44) ~[?:?]                                                                        
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.PluginFileSystemFactory$ClassLoaderFixingFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(PluginFileSystemFactory.java:134) ~[flink-dist-1.18-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.18-SNAPSHOT]
```

Does it mean that there is no way of creating a parquet file sink to azure blob, using the **wasbs** protocol?
If it is possible creating such sink, what changes should I apply to the current implementation?